# Reduce table-cell height to less than font height

Tags: css, cell, padding

Look at http://www.electromontis.net/evoligion/_C/C11.shtml#T11.1 to see the problem. The 7-em right angle brackets are supposed to indicate that the rows above and below combine to produce the row pointed to, and I'd like the extremities of the angle bracket to touch the cell borders. But the table cell height is set by the white space expected by the angle bracket. This is a perfect use for negative padding, which doesn't seem to exist. Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 0):

You could apply something like this to the `.td3` class:

```
transform: translateY(-12px);
line-height: 110px;
```